# (Android, java) Cannot rename a child node twice in Firebase realtime database (Solved: Read the bottom of my first post for answer)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, children

I have a button to rename a child node in firebase database, and an editTextView for users to input a string for the new child node name. On button pressed, the string will be extracted from the editTextView and be used to rename the child node.

In my coding approach to renaming a child node from username "Paul" to username "John", I would : (1) Create a new child node called "John", and (2) Copy the values in "Paul" child node over to "John" child node, and lastly (3) Delete "Paul" child node.

The codes I have written can successfully rename to username "John" without a problem, but say when I want to rename for a second time to a new username called "Ken", on button pressed for the second time, the whole node will be wiped out completely, meaning that there is nothing left there. Why is "Ken" child node gone and how can I fix the code?

---

Here are the screenshots of the datababase console explaining what happens when the button is clicked.

(Picture 1) This is the state before the button is clicked. The initial username is "Paul":
[image: Paul Node]

(Picture 2) This is when the button is pressed for the 1st time to rename to "John". The codes function with no error up to this point:
[image: John Node]

(Picture 3) This is when the button is pressed for the 2nd time to rename again to "Ken". The codes do not function as desired and unfortunatelty delete all nodes and "Ken" will not come up.

[image: No more node appears]

---

Here is the code snippet I've written:
For the record, the string variable "username" is the existing username (here it is "Paul"), the string variable "temporaryUsername" is the new name (here it is "John" on first-time button pressed and is supposed to be "Ken" on second-time button pressed). The editTextView, which is "usernameInputView", is where string variable "temporaryUsername" is extracted from.

```
usernameSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("usernameSharedPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        username = usernameSharedPreferences.getString("userName", "");



renameUserButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                if (username!=null && !username.equals("")) {    //Check that the existing username isn't empty

                        String temporaryUsername = usernameInputView.getText().toString();

                        if (temporaryUsername!=null && !temporaryUsername.equals("")) {

                            // (1) Creatw a new child node (temporaryUsername)
                            mRootReference.child("Users' Input History").child(temporaryUsername).push().setValue("");

                            // (2) Copy the values from the exisiting node (username) to the new node (temporaryUsername)
                            DatabaseReference usersInputHistorySourceNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users' Input History").child(username);
                            final DatabaseReference usersInputHistoryTargetNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users' Input History").child(temporaryUsername);
                            ValueEventListener valueEventListenerForUsersInputHistory = new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    usersInputHistoryTargetNode.setValue(dataSnapshot.getValue()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                            if (task.isComplete()) {
                                                Log.d("User Input History copy", "Success!");
                                            } else {
                                                Log.d("User Input History copy", "Copy failed!");
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
                            };
                            usersInputHistorySourceNode.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListenerForUsersInputHistory);


                           // (3) Remove the existing node (username)
                            mChildReferenceForInputHistory.child(username).removeValue();

                            //Make "username" equal to "temporaryUsername" (meaning to make "temporaryUsername" as the new existing username) and save into SharedPreferences
                        usernameSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("usernameSharedPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
                        usernameSharedPreferences.edit().putString("userName", temporaryUsername).apply();


                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.Your_new_username_is) + temporaryUsername, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.You_have_not_entered_any_username, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }

                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.You_have_not_entered_any_username, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
            });
```

---

Here's what I've tried:

I tried to force run the renaming process twice. I packed the whole code within the OnClickListener into a helper method called renameNode(), and passed renameNode() into the OnClickListener twice consecutively. I thought if the second time doesn't work then I could just force it to run the renaming process once again for the 3rd time, but still I didn't succeed. With this method, not even a single node will appear in the database (which is identical to the situation as shown in Picture 3 above), so I'm out of tricks now. Below are the codes to be exact:

```
    String temporaryUsername;

renameUserButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                if (username!=null && !username.equals("")) {    //Check that the existing username isn't empty

                        temporaryUsername = usernameInputView.getText().toString();

                        renameNode();
                        renameNode();
                        }

                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.You_have_not_entered_any_username, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }

                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.You_have_not_entered_any_username, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
            });



    public void renameNode() {

                        if (temporaryUsername!=null && !temporaryUsername.equals("")) {

                            // (1) Creatw a new child node (temporaryUsername)
                            mRootReference.child("Users' Input History").child(temporaryUsername).push().setValue("");

                            // (2) Copy the values from the exisiting node (username) to the new node (temporaryUsername)
                            DatabaseReference usersInputHistorySourceNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users' Input History").child(username);
                            final DatabaseReference usersInputHistoryTargetNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users' Input History").child(temporaryUsername);
                            ValueEventListener valueEventListenerForUsersInputHistory = new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    usersInputHistoryTargetNode.setValue(dataSnapshot.getValue()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                            if (task.isComplete()) {
                                                Log.d("User Input History copy", "Success!");
                                            } else {
                                                Log.d("User Input History copy", "Copy failed!");
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
                            };
                            usersInputHistorySourceNode.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListenerForUsersInputHistory);


                           // (3) Remove the existing node (username)
                            mChildReferenceForInputHistory.child(username).removeValue();

                            //Make "username" equal to "temporaryUsername" (meaning to make "temporaryUsername" as the new existing username) and save into SharedPreferences
                        usernameSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("usernameSharedPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
                        usernameSharedPreferences.edit().putString("userName", temporaryUsername).apply();


                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.Your_new_username_is) + temporaryUsername, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

---

**(ANSWER) This problem is solved with the help of Khagan Azizov.**

I put "mChildReferenceForInputHistory.child(username).removeValue()" at the wrong position and should move it to one line above "Log.d("User Input History copy", "Success!")".

So here's the chunk of codes after correction:

```
DatabaseReference usersInputHistorySourceNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users' Input History").child(username);
                        final DatabaseReference usersInputHistoryTargetNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users' Input History").child(temporaryUsername);
                        ValueEventListener valueEventListenerForUsersInputHistory = new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                usersInputHistoryTargetNode.setValue(dataSnapshot.getValue()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        if (task.isComplete()) {
                                            **// (3) Remove the existing node (username)
                                            mChildReferenceForInputHistory.child(username).removeValue();**
                                            Log.d("User Input History copy", "Success!");
                                        } else {
                                            Log.d("User Input History copy", "Copy failed!");
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
                        };
                        usersInputHistorySourceNode.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListenerForUsersInputHistory);
```

**Also I'd like to thank GrahamD for pointing me to the right direction on avoiding corrupt data.**

Comment: What does your database look like when you have created a few records? Please post the view from the Firebase DB console here and we can maybe help you.

Comment: @GrahamD , I updated the post with a few screenshots of the database. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Thanks. Before trying to work out why Ken deletes the node (sounds like I'm getting at Ken), I am a bit concerned about your db structure. You don't seem to have a unique id for your users. Is this just a trivial example db structure for this question or is this the version that will go live? There will be more than one John, Ken, Dave in the world so that could be a big problem.

Comment: Also, if you have a unique, never changing key for the user and keep their name as a property of that key then changing names becomes trivial.

Comment: This is the version that I think will go live. I heard of the neccesity of a unique id (or "key" as you suggested) for users for things to work properly but my level of coding is not enough to comprehend how to make that work, even if I dug the web trying to find articles explaining that. Is it possible you could show me what you mean programically or perhaps reflect that in my codes?

Comment: So are your users logging in? If so, what are you using to authenticate them? Whatever you are using will be allocating a unique id, which you can use. If they are not logging in then you need to make sure Firebase allocates a unique id. You are already using the the right statement to achieve that ie. the .push().setvalue(), which as you see creates a unique key. Having said all this, you really need to put the time in to understand how Firebase works and how you should structure the db. Otherwise, it will bite you back in poor performance, corrupt data and high cost.

Comment: Not yet but I will use Firebase Authenticatication in the next phase so the users will be able to log in. I'll take note of the "push().setvalue()" part and dig in on how Firebase works to eventually implement the unique id method. More than one Johns and Kens could inevitably disrupt or override my database as you so kinldy reminded.

Comment: You're welcome. Your code will change completely when u fix the unique user id problem. That is why I didn't bother talking about code fixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you changed the data in username variable after first button press?

Comment: Yes, in the section where I annotated " // (3) Remove the existing node (username)", SharedPreferences is called to change the username variable to the value of the temporaryUsername variable and save, after the button is pressed each time. To conclude, after each button click, the username variable will be replaced with the latest value of temporaryUsername entered by the user.

Comment: Ok but in this line DatabaseReference usersInputHistorySourceNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users' Input History").child(username); you still calling username which may have previous data in it right?

Comment: I mean you may changed SharedPreferences but you have not assigned this new value to username

Comment: Yes, the username variable has the previous value when calling usersInputHistorySourceNode, and yes I change the username variable in SharedPreferences. I forgot to mention I did assign the latest value of temporaryUsername to the username variable, by writing this line of code in the onCreate section: usernameSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("usernameSharedPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);       username = usernameSharedPreferences.getString("userName", "");  Therefore the app will remeber the new value of username on each launch. I'm updating the code snippet in my post.

Comment: Maybe it is becouse of timing.You may delete data before you write it.Try to remove mChildReferenceForInputHistory.child(username).removeValue();
here if (task.isComplete()) {
                                                Log.d("User Input History copy", "Success!");
                                            }

Comment: Fantastic! This solved the problem. I put "mChildReferenceForInputHistory.child(username).removeValue()" at the wrong position and should move it to one line above "Log.d("User Input History copy", "Success!")".  Thanks, Khagan Azizov.